# Prevent overlapping range values on a slider (noUiSlider)

Tags: javascript, slider, nouislider

I have a set of 3 ranges on a slider consisting of 30 days and beyond (see [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nlourenco/pen/KKMWLXQ)). At the moment, the values between the 3 ranges overlap by one day.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var unconstrainedValues = document.getElementById("unconstrained-values");

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: [0, 7],
    padding: [0, 1],
    connect: [true, true, true],
    range: {
        min: 0,
        max: 31
    },
    pips: {
        mode: "values",
        values: [0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 30],
        density: 3
    },
    step: 1,
    range: {
        min: [0],
        max: [31]
    },
    format: wNumb({
        // https://refreshless.com/wnumb/
        decimals: 0,
        mark: ".",
        thousad: ",",
        prefix: ""
        // suffix: ' p.p.'
    }),
    tooltips: true
});

var nodes = [
    document.getElementById("daily-rate-a"), // 0
    document.getElementById("daily-rate-b"), // 0
    document.getElementById("daily-rate-c") // 0
];

slider.noUiSlider.on("update", function (
    values,
    handle,
    unencoded,
    isTap,
    positions
) {
    nodes[handle].innerHTML = values[handle];
});

// var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.noUi-tooltip');
// console.log(tooltips);
// tooltips.forEach(tooltip => tooltip.classList.add('tooltips-active'));

var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
var input3 = document.getElementById("input3");
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");

var connect = slider.querySelectorAll(".noUi-connect");
var classes = ["c-1-color", "c-2-color", "c-3-color"];

for (var i = 0; i < connect.length; i++) {
    connect[i].classList.add(classes[i]);
}

slider.noUiSlider.on("update", function (values) {
    unconstrainedValues.innerHTML = values.join(" - ");
});
```

Current result:

- 0-15
- 15-20
- 20-Infinity

Desired result:

- 0-15
- 16-20
- 21-Infinity

Essentially, the start of the next range should never be the same value as the end of the previous range. (Both 0 in Range A and Infinity in Range C are static and never change.) How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `margin` option while creating

```js
margin: 1
```

```js
noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: [0, 7],
    ...
    margin: 1 // Newly added
    ...
    tooltips: true
});
```

### Range 3 Implementation

- option change

```
start: [0,16,21]
connect: [true, true, true, true]
```

- Event function change in `noUiSlider.on`

```
values[0 ~ 2]
```

So, a working js/html will be

```html
<script src=""https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/13.1.3/nouislider.min.js">
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <tr class="th">
            <td>SEQUENCE</td>
            <td>RATE</td>
            <td>DAYS ACTIVE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="daily-rate-a">
            <td>Daily Rate A</td>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="0.00" required name="price" min="0" value="" step="0.01" title="Currency"></td>
            <td><span class="example-val" id="unconstrained-value-a"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="daily-rate-b">
            <td>Daily Rate B</td>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="0.00" required name="price" min="0" value="" step="0.01" title="Currency"></td>
            <td><span class="example-val" id="unconstrained-value-b"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="daily-rate-c">
            <td>Daily Default<span class="required">*</span></td>
            <td><input type="number" placeholder="0.00" required name="price" min="0" value="" step="0.01" title="Currency"></td>
            <td><span class="example-val" id="unconstrained-value-c"></span></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <h3>Agreement Day Timeline</h3>

    <div id="slider"></div>
    <div class="infinity">∞</div>
</div>
```

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("slider");
var unconstrainedValueA = document.getElementById("unconstrained-value-a");
var unconstrainedValueB = document.getElementById("unconstrained-value-b");
var unconstrainedValueC = document.getElementById("unconstrained-value-c");

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: [0, 16, 21],
    padding: [0, 1],
    margin: 1,
    connect: [true, true, true, true],
    range: {
        min: 0,
        max: 31
    },
    pips: {
        mode: "values",
        values: [0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 30],
        density: 3
    },
    step: 1,
    range: {
        min: [0],
        max: [31]
    },
    format: wNumb({
        // https://refreshless.com/wnumb/
        decimals: 0,
        mark: ".",
        thousad: ",",
        prefix: ""
        // suffix: ' p.p.'
    }),
    tooltips: true
});

var nodes = [
    document.getElementById("daily-rate-a"), // 0
    document.getElementById("daily-rate-b"), // 0
    document.getElementById("daily-rate-c") // 0
];

var tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('.noUi-tooltip');
console.log(tooltips);
tooltips.forEach(tooltip => tooltip.classList.add('tooltips-active'));

var input1 = document.getElementById("input1");
var input2 = document.getElementById("input2");
var input3 = document.getElementById("input3");
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control");

var connect = slider.querySelectorAll(".noUi-connect");
var classes = ["c-1-color", "c-2-color", "c-3-color"];

for (var i = 0; i < connect.length; i++) {
    connect[i].classList.add(classes[i]);
}

slider.noUiSlider.on("update", function (values) {
    unconstrainedValueA.innerHTML = values[0] + ' - ' + (values[1] - 1);
    unconstrainedValueB.innerHTML = values[1] + ' - ' + (values[2] - 1);
    unconstrainedValueC.innerHTML = values[2] + ' - ' + '∞';
});
```

Comment: Do you know how I would go about actually displaying the start of Range 3 (Daily Default)?

Comment: @ArnoldPalmer Check the js/HTML. Have changed some elements in HTML as well as some js code.